# PHP PDO Problme

Tags: php, pdo

```
public function store($name , $description ,$created ,$modified ,$created_by,$modified_by,$deleted_at,$id) {

    try{

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->created = $created;
        $this->modified = $modified;
        $this->created_by = $created_by;
        $this->modified_by = $modified_by;
        $this->deleted_at = $deleted_at;
        $this->$id = $id;
        $sql = "UPDATE `categories` SET `name` = :name, `description` = :description, `created` = :created, modified = :modified ,`created_by` = :created_by, `modified_by` = :modified_by, `deleted_at` = :deleted_at WHERE `id` = :id ";

        $stmt =$this->conn->prepare($sql);


        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':description',$this->description,\PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':created',$this->created,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':modified',$this->modified,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':created_by', $this->created_by,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':modified_by',$this->modified_by,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':deleted_at',$this->deleted_at,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id,\PDO::PARAM_INT);
        //$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        //print_r($stmt);
        $stmt->execute();
        var_dump($stmt);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

even there is no error but not working properly

Comment: "not working properly" as in ... ?

Comment: Any reason for the backslash before the parameter types?

Comment: You need to explain what you are observing your code doing.

Comment: "not working properly" has never helped anyone, anywhere at any time to find a solution or get an answer. You have to describe what that means exactly. What happens? What does _not_ happen? We cannot _guess_ all that. You have to tell us!

Comment: `$this->$id = $id;`  remove the $

Comment: Maybe you should report/display errors: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$this->$id = $id; to $this->id = $id;
```